# Android: Custom Google Hangout like Listview

Tags: android, listview

I am creating an app with ListView like that of Google Hangout. The list item consists of Imageview on the left and some text on the right. See the image below.

[image: Google Hangout]

I don't know how to show these images. When there is single person i want to show only one circular. However, if there are more persons I want to show images as per above photograph. Please help me out. How can I do this?

Comment: have you solved this? can you post how you solve

Comment: @LittleGirl Yes I solved it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem myself.

There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. Use canvas to generate a Bitmap will be a combined bitmap of all the images. Below is the code for generating Bitmap of four people (four circles).

   ```
   public static Bitmap customImageFour(Context context, Bitmap[] bitmaps, int size) {

       Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[0], size/2, size/2, false);
       Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[1], size/2, size/2, false);
       Bitmap bmp3 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[2], size/2, size/2, false);
       Bitmap bmp4 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[3], size/2, size/2, false);

       Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
       Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1);
       bitmap1 = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap1, bitmap1.getWidth()/2);
       Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp2);
       bitmap2 = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap2, bitmap2.getWidth()/2);
       Bitmap bitmap3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp3);
       bitmap3 = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap3, bitmap3.getWidth()/2);
       Bitmap bitmap4 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp4);
       bitmap4 = getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap4, bitmap4.getWidth()/2);
       Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, conf);
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(finalBitmap);
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0f, 0f, null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, bitmap1.getWidth(), 0f, null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap3, 0f, bitmap1.getHeight(), null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap4, bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(), null);

       return finalBitmap;
   }
   ```
2. Another way is, instead of using single ImageView you can use a RelativeLayout and add ImageViews in it through code. If there are two people then create two ImageViews and add them in the layout, if there are four people then create four ImageViews and add them in the layout.